# SEO friendly url on client side

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

What are the possible ways to create a SEO friendly url for linking internal web page? I've read multiple forums about .htaccess with php. Is there any other ways to do it through client side?

Essentially, is there a client-side way to go from the home page to about page and have the url be **customDomainName/about** instead of **customDomainName/about.html**? Any links to tutorials that can achieve this will be helpful!

Comment: no. you need to this server-side.

Comment: URLs are routed server-side. There's no way to do that client-side. As for all the ways to do it server-side, that's too broad. And questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please read about [ask] questions here.

Answer (score 0):

A client side can only be done if you build your webpage complete AJAX based.
This means on every click your visitors browser make an ajax request and refresh the page content. In reality your visitor never loaded a new page only the browser updates the content.
Here a post about modifieng the url: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

This way is to complex. YOu have also to look for direct access the modified url with hashtags.